# Push-to-talk switch to access Siri/Homekit?

Tags: siri-remote

I do not want an always listening- device and would like to be able to control HomeKit automation with a push-to-talk switch, that I would install on the wall in multiple places in the house, so that anyone – without using a phone or an always-listening-HomePod – can access the switch, push it and request Siri to run a scene and release it. Somethings similar to the behavior of the Apple TV remote’s microphone button’s functionality.

Surely such a Bluetooth button or switch exists! Can you help me find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HomePod has two settings regarding activation functionality, which can be toggled independently.

> - Disable “Hey Siri” requests: Turn off Listen for “Hey Siri”.
> - Disable activating Siri using HomePod touch controls: Turn off Touch and Hold for Siri.

https://support.apple.com/guide/homepod/apde6dc8093d/homepod

Therefore you can disable Hey Siri and only press and hold the top of the device to activate Siri to listen for commands.

Comment: Awesome!  That’s an alternative. I was looking to replace one of the light switches on the wall though…